# How to read a file from internet?

Tags: c#, file

simple question:
I have an file online (txt). How to read it and check if its there?
(C#.net 2.0)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

from http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

```
    HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create("myurl");

        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();
            // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string tempString = null;
    int    count      = 0;

    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
        if (count != 0)
        {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

            // continue building the string
            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

    // print out page source
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Nowadays it's _much_ simpler: just instantiate a `WebClient` and call `DownloadString` on it.

Comment: Where do the variables `sb` and `buf` come from? Also the link is dead now.

Comment: sb is StringBuilder and buf is Byte[]

Answer (score 86):

I think the WebClient-class is appropriate for that:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://yoururl/test.txt");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openread.aspx

Comment: Could you fill in the prerequisites for this? I'm getting `The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found`

Comment: WebClient can be found in System.Net - a quick Google for "dotnet WebClient" usually turns up the Microsoft reference page which tells you the hierarchy.

Answer (score 11):

A little bit easier way:

```
string fileContent = new WebClient().DownloadString("yourURL");
```

Comment: `WebClient` is obsolete. Use `HttpCLient` instead.

Answer (score 8):

First, you can download the binary file:

```
public byte[] GetFileViaHttp(string url)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadData(url);
    }
}
```

Then you can make array of strings for text file (assuming UTF-8 and that it is a text file):

```
var result = GetFileViaHttp(@"http://example.com/index.html");
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
string[] strArr = str.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You'll receive every (except empty) line of text in every array field.

Comment: This is for Windows line ending encoding. If you wish to split lines for Linux use "\n".

Comment: better to use new string[] { Environment.NewLine } for generic soltuion

Answer (score 4):

an alternative to `HttpWebRequest` is [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

```
    // create a new instance of WebClient
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    // set the user agent to IE6
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    try
    {
        // actually execute the GET request
        string ret = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/");

        // ret now contains the contents of the webpage
        Console.WriteLine("First 256 bytes of response: " + ret.Substring(0,265));
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        // WebException.Status holds useful information
        Console.WriteLine(we.Message + "\n" + we.Status.ToString());
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException ne)
    {
        // other errors
        Console.WriteLine(ne.Message);
    }
```

example from http://www.daveamenta.com/2008-05/c-webclient-usage/

Answer (score 0):

This is too much easier:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

...

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        //... client.options
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://.........");
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

"WebClient" and "StreamReader" are disposables. The content of file will be into "content" var.

The client var contains several configuration options.

The default configuration could be called as:

```
string content = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://.........");
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at `System.Net.WebClient`, the docs even have an example of retrieving the file.

But testing if the file exists implies asking for the file and catching the exception if it's not there.