# Host a service written in linux and consume it through C# running in Windows 7

Tags: c#, java, linux, service

I need to write a web service in linux, Through a java program. The service provided should be a text file. 
Say whenever the client access the service, It should return a file say /tmp/sample.txt.

And the problem is, the client is a C# program which is running on the windows 7. And the linux will be running as Virtual machine in Windows.

What I need is:

1. How can i host a service in linux which is written in java.
2. How can i access it in windows client whch is a c# program.

I would be happy if anyone help me on this.

Comment: It sounds like you've already got it figured it out, write the application in Java, run it on Linux.  The Windows machine doesn't care what platform it's accessing via a web service, nor does C#.

Comment: @NickVeys:  What steps i need to follow to host it as a service in linux?

Comment: Different distributions handle services or daemons differently.  To be honest I'd simply Google "custom daemon <my linux distribution>" and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Tomcat into Apache for hosting Java sites on Linux. Here is the site for Apache Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/. Don't forget you will also need the JDK installed on the Linux server so that it can run Java programs.

Here's a site that can help you get started with it on a RedHat distribution of Linux: http://easylinuxtutorials.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on.html

As long as it has an accessible URL, you can just make a call to the URL, then read the file either by saving it to a local directory and reading it off the downloaded file, or directly reading it into a file stream. Check [How to read a file from internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471209/how-to-read-a-file-from-internet)

Answer (score 0):

You mean host a service in Java-WS on Linux! Nothing is "written in Linux"

Here're two pieces which shows...

**STEP 1.** Create a VM on Fedora/Linux with SFTP so you can upload your Java-ws created (with Netbeans, or a notepad!) on your Windows Workstation to the VM.
https://gridwizard.wordpress.com/2014/12/28/install-tomcat-on-fedora-vm-for-msdev/

**STEP 2.** Create a simple java-ws, put under Tomcat, then consume from C#
https://gridwizard.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/java-ws-and-dotnet-interop-example/